# Do I really need to shutdown MySql server to set Global variable log_bin_trust_function_creators?

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem while creating a function in MySql :

```
You do not have the SUPER privilege and
binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe
log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

While searching I found that below command will fix the issue

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

Do I really need to shutdown MySql server to set Global variable log_bin_trust_function_creators ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to restart mysql to change this setting. The [mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) says it is a dynamic variable, so it can be changed via the `set` statement in your question.